# Office 365 mail-app for Outlook 2013 -2007

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I am wondering when i create my 365 mail app for outlook, will this work with Outlook 2010 and 2007?  if so is there an obvious limitation?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Office Apps can work in Outlook 2013 and later versions. See [Mail apps for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx) for more information.